# How does work item type "Blocked" influence Lead & Cycle Time?

Tags: azure-devops

We're wondering if changing the ticket type from Bug / PBI to "Blocked" has a negative impact on measuring Lead and Cycle time, since the entire type of the ticket changes back and forth. Does the counter reset? Thx!

Comment: Is that "Blocked" a custom Work Item Type? If so, what state do you specify in it?

Comment: Ok, If I don't misunderstand, the counter you mean is the Cycle/lead time widget? It won't reset if we disable the bug/pbi.

Comment: To clairfy. Without further configuration, Azure Devops has the Ticket Type "Blocked". I refer to changing a Bug or PBI to "Blocked" and then back, instead of adding a State and using that.

Comment: Cycle & Lead Time i a metric Azure Devops tracks, for widgets or dashboards e.g. visualization in Power BI.

Comment: As I know, for Basic, Agile, Scrum, CMMI there's no pre-defined `Blocked` Work Item Type(If your ticket type means WIT?) there. So this should be one custom WIT if I don't misunderstand. Hi, does the PBI above refers to Product Backlog Item?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about whether adding new custom WIT(work item type) or disable existing Bug/PBI would reset current `Cycle/Lead` time. As I know, the result of the counter(`cycle/lead` time) won't be affected by whether we disable the default WIT like Bug,PBI...

This is one of my Cycle Time widget(Before disabling User Story):

[image]

Then I disabled the User Story and defined new custom WIT in `Organization Settings=>Process`, the counter(lead/cycle time) about UserStory didn't reset.

It's just we now can't create new UserStory WIT any more. So if you change the WIT from Bug/PBI to "Blocked", the time about Bug/PBI before still exist and won't reset.

Hope it helps. If I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me:)